# Log4j - display full exception information including inner exception(s)

Tags: log4j

Our log4j (properties below) gives us the Exception.getMessage(), but that's all. I need it to log the stack trace and all inner exceptions, with the stack trace for each of those.

How do I do this?

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\temp\\JavaEngine.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%x - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using log4j 1, I don't believe there is anything wrong with your configuration.

I used your configuration in conjunction with the following app:

```
package log4j;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.IOException;

public class App {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(App.class);

    private static Throwable nestedThrowable() {
        return new Throwable("Thrown error", new IOException("Some Error"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.error("test error", nestedThrowable());
    }
}
```

This resulted in the following output:

```
2020-01-20 15:04:02 ERROR App: - test error
java.lang.Throwable: Thrown error
        at log4j.App.nestedThrowable(App.java:11)
        at log4j.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Some Error
```

As such, my suggestion would be to make sure that the [Logger API](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html) is being used correctly to ensure that the `Throwable` is being passed as the last argument, e.g. `error(Object message, Throwable thrown)`